# Using an xml to replaces nodes in another bigger xml C#

Tags: c#, xml

Hi I have to replace certain nodes from 1 XML to a bigger `web.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
  <VFPData>
    <site>
      <sitename></sitename>
      <appname></appname>
      <cookie>.cookiename</cookie>
      <host></host>
      <port>1234</port>
      <database></database>
      <userid></userid>
      <password></password>
    </site>
  </VFPData>
```

So I have to copy over say the `<port>` to the `web.config`.

Comment: Are you asking about modifying web.config at runtime?

Comment: I assume it's not just the <port> node you want to copy but multiple nodes. You could do this by reading the text file into a stream, copy the part you want and then append the current web.config file. Look at Stream, MemoryStream and FileStream as this may help.

Comment: @ryadavilli No. this will be done when its off

Comment: ... What? I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean, when it's off? If you want to reply to a comment, use the @ symbol, such as @user1947998

Comment: @Dave Rook Going to look into your solution Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem them? Why cant you copy them over now ?

Comment: @ryadavilli since i had no clue how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the StreamWriter and StreamReader if you want to treat both files as text files.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
        // This text is added only once to the file. 
        if (!File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            // Create a file to write to. 
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                sw.WriteLine("And");
                sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
            }   
        }

        // This text is always added, making the file longer over time 
        // if it is not deleted. 
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) 
        {
            sw.WriteLine("This");
            sw.WriteLine("is Extra");
            sw.WriteLine("Text");
        }   

        // Open the file to read from. 
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) 
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx)

Right, this covers streams and would work great for text. However, you're editing XML and so can go one step further. Since both are in XML, you could use the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) object (which will allow Linq). This will allow you to read the original stream, store the node to copy as a variable, then open the web.config file and add the node.